# ¿Cómo se originaron las formas "don" y "doña"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

Según el diccionario, las palabras *don* y *doña* tienen la siguiente etimología:

> **[don, doña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E7fKGDe)**
>
> Del lat. *domĭnus* 'señor'; la forma f., del lat. *domĭna*.

Sin embargo, aunque su origen queda claro lo que no me queda claro es la evolución que han sufrido para llegar desde *domĭnus* hasta *don*. Y más teniendo en cuenta que las mismas palabras *domĭnus, domĭna* también dieron origen a *[dueño/a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EEsL9LT)*.

Así pues, ¿cuál fue la evolución que nos dio *don, doña*? ¿Por qué el femenino originó una *ñ* cuando otras palabras que acaban en *-ón* tienen el femenino en *-ona*? (Ejemplos: *abusona, besucona, campeona*...)

Comment: @walen ¿y por qué _donna_ y no _dona_?

Comment: En neerlandes y ingles, se usa Dom para el orden eclesiástico. Yo tambien creo que es del origen de *dominus*. De ahi derivo Dom -> *Dom Perignon*, la iglesia de Utrech *DomKerk* (Dom+kerk), la plaza *Dom*... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominus_(title) *Domina* se abrevia *Dna.* ->  Donna, doña.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las alternancias *don/dueño* y *doña/dueña* parecen ser resultado de un proceso de cambio fonológico diferencial, aunque a primera vista sugieren [dobletes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics)) etimológicos. Paso a explicar más abajo, notando que la fuente de ambas hipótesis es [este sitio web](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?don), no muy conocido por su confiabilidad, aunque en este caso las explicaciones son claras y plausibles.

Un doblete etimológico es un par de palabras que derivan del mismo origen pero que tienen formas diferentes, generalmente porque fueron incorporadas a la misma lengua en dos ocasiones diferentes. En castellano esto suele pasar con los cultismos: la misma palabra latina experimentó por un lado su cambio regular al pasar al romance y al castellano, y por otro fue preservada o reincorporada en el registro literario o formal en una forma más conservadora. Por ejemplo, son dobletes *llave* y *clave*, *hembra* y *fémina*, etc.

Esto podría explicar *don* vs. *dueño* si asumimos que el latín *dominus* fue apocopado a **dom* (cuando era un título) en tiempos muy tempranos, antes de que el romance diptongara la *o* corta. Pero parece que no fue así.

En cambio y por lo que explica la fuente citada, lo que ocurrió fue que, cuando se usaban como títulos frente al nombre propio, las palabras que luego serían *don* y *doña* se hicieron átonas, es decir, proclíticos sin acentuación propia, como los artículos. (Cuando uno dice *don Felipe*  fonéticamente sólo se "escucha" una palabra llana de cuatro sílabas.)

En muchas de las lenguas romances la antigua *o* corta del latín (luego *o* abierta [ɔ]) diptongó, pero sólo cuando era vocal tónica. Ésta es la razón de que en castellano existan los verbos con raíz alternante del tipo *volar* ~ *vuelo*. Fue lo que pasó en este caso: *don* < **domne* < *domine* (vocativo de *dominus*) perdió su acentuación propia al incorporarse fonéticamente a la palabra siguiente, y su vocal dejó de estar sujeta a la regla de diptongación. Lo mismo ocurrió con *doña* < *donna* < *domina*.

La razón de que *doña* tenga una *ñ* es que *domina* primero sincopó en *domna*, que luego se simplificó a *donna*, y la *nn* geminada se transformó en *ñ* en castellano. En realidad, viendo el par *don/doña*, lo que alguien sin conocimientos de castellano podría preguntarse es por qué *don* no es cambio **doñ*. En castellano no hubo una palatalización tan generalizada de /l/ y /n/ en distintas posiciones, como sí la hubo (por ejemplo) en catalán.